# How much time passed between seasons 2 and 3

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-rebels

I just watched the first half of the first episode of Season 3 of Star Wars: Rebels.  Ezra has grown quite a bit, and Kanan has a beard, so clearly more than a few weeks have passed.

How much time (in-universe) passed between the ending of the last episode in Season 2, and the start of the first episode of Season 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Six months passed between season 2 finale and season 3 first episode. Season 2 is set in 3BBY (Before Battle of Yavin), season 3 is in 2BBY.

> [@Voldemorgoth](https://twitter.com/Voldemorgoth)
>   six months pass between the S2 finale and the S3 premiere. We're
>   about 2 years from Ep4
>
> — Pablo Hidalgo (@pablohidalgo) September
>   2, 2016

Comment: How old is Luke at the end of S3 ? He doesn't look like 16 years old adolescent in scene where aunt Beru calls him and he runs like little boy.

Comment: @rs.29 Yes he's 16. I read they used Ezra's model as a basis for Luke (he's 16 too).